# how to rotate a img in visible-xs and visible-sm bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a class `row2` for the `img` that I want to rotate.
There are three `img` elements that I want to rotate when the visibility is `xs` and `sm`.

Now my question is how can I rotate a `img` when the max visibility is `visible-xs` and `visible-sm` without the rotating of `visible-md` and `visible-lg`?

```
       <div class="row2">
          <div class="visible-lg col-lg-3" id="particulier">

          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="particulier">
            <a href="http://www.egcomputerspecialisten.nl/page/176"><img alt="" src="particulier.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a>
         </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="webshop">
            <a href="http://shop.egcomputerspecialisten.nl/?pk_campaign=egcs.nl&pk_kwd=menu_link "><img alt="" src="webshop.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2" id="zakelijk">
            <a href="http://www.egcomputerspecialisten.nl/news/8"><img alt="" src="zakelijk.png" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="visible-lg col-lg-3" id="particulier">

          </div>
        </div>
```

Style:

```
.row2 {
        -ms-transform: rotate(-0.5deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-0.5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        transform: rotate(-0.5deg);
    }
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct @Panto, bootstrap has the following breakpoints by [default](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

```
/* xs */
@media (max-width: 767px) {}
/* sm */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}
/* md */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {}
/* lg */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

so @Twan in your case you have to write classes inside

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {} /* this covers xs and sm */
```

One more note on your code.
There is no need to use visible-lg with col-lg-X classes.

Answer (score 0):

Using media query

for xs screens

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  img {
     //style
  }
}
```

for sm screens

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    img {
     //style
  }
}
```

Comment: I know how that works but they are teaching me how to use bootstrap for this. But i cant figger it out..